# Crackling and sound delay in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

Whenever I open any video or audio with my earphone plugged in I get to hear a crackle before I actually hear the audio.

I used to play 2 audios, with one audio in mute and other audio which I want to hear in volume up. When I use this method I don't hear any sort of disturbance.

I tried:

1. pulse audio kill
2. removed speech dispatcher
3. `nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Nothing solved the problem.

Comment: Same issue for me, when listening audio on Clementine and videos on Firefox